# Does hadoop reducer have a timeout for inputs?

Tags: java, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a hadoop job that I'm trying to run on a 8-node Windows HDP cluster.  The job has over 137000 inputs and it processes between 84% and 92% of the map tasks in about 3.5 hours.  Then the reducer restarts at 0% and the map tasks rerun.  The job never finishes.

My question is, is there a timeout on the reducer reading the map outputs or blocks from dfs that is causing the reducer to restart?  Or if the reducer hits a limit of some sort, will it produce an error message that will help me determine the cause.  My first hurdle was that the default queue would only allow 100000 tasks, but the job errored out with a message indicating as such.

The version of hadoop I'm working with is the version you get with Microsoft HDInsight.  It appears to be a hadoop 1.1.0 snapshot for windows (Hortonworks Data Platform 1.0.1 Developer Preview for Windows).  I set properties to give the client tasks 8000mb of memory.  Since the jobtracker is running as started from a windows service, I can't tell how much memory the VM is actually started with.

Comment: What version of Hadoop?  What amount of memory does the JobTracker have?

Comment: That is a bug, I just can't find the jira issue for it.

Answer (score 0):

Did u use counters in map task? Is your map task CPU intensive? if yes you need to use counters to make sure Hadoop doesn't think your job is hanging, instead it is processing.